# Schengen Visa Extension - Important Personal Reasons

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens, visa-extensions

My US citizen step daughter is taking a study abroad semester in Europe in Schengen visa countries. The program is exactly 90 days so she will exhaust the period allowed for her to stay taking this program. We looked at extending her trip for 10 days for a family trip to Portugal but of course we need a Visa extension.

How difficult is it to obtain an extension for "Important Personal Reasons"? I know there is no guarantee of obtaining one. And I take it she should apply for a visa with a Portuguese embassy as this is where she would like to visit.

Comment: "The program is exactly 90 days": on what date is her presence first required?  On what date is it last required?  Is there any chance that she could spend her weekends outside the Schengen area, such as in the UK?  What is the "important" reason for the family trip?

Comment: I asked about the specific dates because if, for example, classes start on Monday 16 Sep and end on Friday 13 Dec then she has only 1 day of leeway (that's 89 days by the Schengen rules). She would already need a national visa just to arrive the day before her first class and leave the day after the last. If she gets a national visa, the days covered by that visa aren't counted for the 90/180 calculation, and the problem goes away. Similarly, if she can make (e.g.) 5 trips outside Schengen (e.g., to the UK), leaving on Friday and returning on Monday, that gets her ten more days in Schengen.

Answer (score 4):

As she is a US citizen, I'm assuming that she is doing this course of study using her short-stay visa-free privileges. This allows her 90 days in any 180 day period. There is no "extension of permitted stay" for short stays regardless of whether you are a visa-exempt or visa-required national. If she wanted to stay over 90 days in any 180 day period then she would have to have petitioned for a D-visa.

[The Austrians](https://oead.at/en/to-austria/entry-and-residence/visa-c-or-visa-d/) have this to say:

> In principle it is not possible to apply for a visa in Austria nor to have it renewed/extended. Once the visa expires you have to – unless you have been granted a residence title – leave the Schengen area.

According to the [European External Action Service](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf):

> 18. **Can my visa be extended**?
>
> When  applying  for  a  visa  extension,  you  must  show  that  due  to  force  majeure  or  for humanitarian reasons or for serious personal reasons it is not possible for you to leave the territory of Member States before the expiry of your visa or the authorized period of stay.

In short, not really. She will have to leave after her 90 days if she wants to obey the rules.

Comment: In theory, Portugal could issue a C visa with limited territorial validity.  I practice it seems highly unlikely.

Answer (score -5):

**Question:**

Does she actually have a Visa or is she travelling on the 90/180 rule as a visa free person?

---

Based on the given samples, **private** reasons do not seem to fullfil the condition:

> [Examples of important personal reasons](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324785/en/):
>   Urgent business or professional reasons which were **not foreseeable before entry**

However the last portion does offer a chance for a reasonable solution.

Assuming that no booking for the trip for the rest of the family has been made, an clearly stated letter of intention that, on condition that your step daughter leave to remain is extended, that a common vacation of the whole family would be made - that was not part of the original plan.

Together with the [Application form](https://www.berlin.de/formularverzeichnis/?formular=/labo/zuwanderung/_assets/mdb-f402068-labo_4617_visaverl__ngerung_dt_engl_t__rk.pdf) she should apply for this at the local Foreigners office (you may have to use a form from that local office).

It would then be up to them to deside to make an exception or not.

**Note:**

This is county specific, so each country may deal with this differently. In Germany an extension may only be applied for locally and if extended it is done immediately. Going to the Portuguese embassy may not be of much use.

Comment: That rule clearly states that it's about reasons that were *not foreseeable*, not merely *not part of the original plan*. It will be hard to argue that a family vacation was not foreseeable.

Comment: @Henrikyou mean the Guideline sample. This officials duer have an amount of leeway for such decisions. If they come to the conclusion that it is **not against**  the public interest to make an exception, then they the authority to do so. In this case it is in the public interest to do so (Family reunion). The economic interest also (earnings inside portugal). Only the responsible authority can make the final decision,  based on the circumstances. No harm will come if refused. Exceptions prove the rule in a humain society.

Comment: Is applying for the extension really practical? If the OP applies soon after entry it will make it harder to convince officials that the family holiday was not foreseeable before entry. If the OP applies later, the timeframe for a reply (no idea what this is) in theory means the trip for the rest of the family would have to be booked ‘last minute’. The family could book their holiday during the OP’s 3 month stay, or the OP could follow @Phoog’s suggestion and spend time out of Schengen. The idea of ‘family reunion’ at the end of a 90 day stay is odd - the OP could just go home to be reunited.

Comment: @Traveller Admitaly bad planing (or circumstances changed). But is not illegal to ask. It would be illegal to overstay. This about 10 extra days for another purpose, with her family where the other members possibly have never been to and share a common experience. The European Union will not sink into the ocean because of this. I don't see this as a missuse of the system. If the official judges it in the same way then it will be granted. If not it won't. If the OP doesn't ask, they will never know. Important is only that it be done in the proper manner.

Comment: I don't see how a family reunion is in the public interest, especially not one taking place abroad (as @Traveller says the OP could just go home). Earnings inside a Schengen country is also to be expected with any visa application, not all are granted, proving that there are many considerations that are far more important.

Comment: @Hendrik be it as it may. I believe such an application has a chance of success. Your Earnings argument does not hold in this case. If the other family members do not come at all **soly** because an extra 10 days is not granted, then it is an avoidable loss. The sole question is: is the granting of an extra 10 days **against** the public interest in this situation? I believe no.

Comment: I suspect this discussion is moot - if the OP is entering visa-free as a US citizen there is no ‘visa’ and therefore surely nothing exists that can actually be extended. If it were that easy to extend the 90 day period there’d be a lot less questions on TSE about overstaying!

Comment: @Traveller presumably there is a provision for visa-free visitors, analogous to the provision for extending short-term visas, to account for cases of *force majeur* or similar circumstances.  Perhaps it involves the issue of some sort of residence title by the appropriate office rather than extending the validity of an existing visa.  But it doesn't make sense that (for example) a severe illness at the end of a visit would have a more adverse impact on a visa-free visitor than it would on a visitor who holds a visa.

Comment: @Traveller it is indeed that exact same process, but without the C-Visa in the passport. It is telling the Border Control through an entry in the passport, to add X days to the entry stamp date calculation upon exit.

Comment: @Crog should your daughter take this advice and it succeeds, a image would be interesting to see what exactly is placed in the passport.